# what is the meaning of time_pretransfer in curl

Tags: curl

I met a problem:

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_namelookup}::%{time_connect}::%{time_pretransfer}::%{time_starttransfer}::%{time_total}::%{speed_download} "https://xxx"
```

When I used this command to test a http link through public network, it returned data like this:

0.004::1.008::1.024::60.805::60.805::0.000

it costed a lot of time in time_starttransfer.

So my question is, what does it mean when time_starttransfer costs a long time? It's a network problem or a server problem? And What is the meaning of time_pretransfer, I checked man page of curl, it says "it took from the start until the file transfer is  just  about  to begin"，I don't understand very well.
Any help will do, thx

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this as well. To me, a networking novice, the man page description does not tell me enough.

Answer (score 0):

According to [curl performance metrics cheat sheet](https://speedtestdemon.com/a-guide-to-curls-performance-metrics-how-to-analyze-a-speed-test-result/), `time_pretransfer` is just an alias for either `time_connect` (HTTP only) or `time_appconnect` (HTTPS only).

In your case, I need to know the numbers to know whether it is network or server problem.

If `time_transfer - time_pretransfer` is large number, then this is server problem. Server has already received request. This is the time it takes for the server to prepare response.

Anything before time_pretransfer is more likely to be network problem instead of server, unless the server is extremely congested with numerous connections (unlikely since a single server can take thousands of simultaneous connections).